# I generate some annotations in pdf by using itextpdf, but annotations unable searched when open pdf by acrobat reader

Tags: java, pdf, itext

```
PdfAnnotation annotation = null;
PdfContentByte cb = pdfCopy.getDirectContent();
try {
    cb.setRGBColorFill(0, 0, 0);
    cb.setFontAndSize(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, "",BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), colorConfig.getColorConfigDomainFontSize());
    float borderWidth = 0f;
    if (null != colorConfig.getColorSchemaBorderWidthVariable() && colorConfig.getColorSchemaBorderWidthVariable() > 0) {
        borderWidth = colorConfig.getColorSchemaBorderWidthVariable();
    }
    annot.setCrfAnnotWidth(annot.getCrfAnnotWidth() + borderWidth);
    annot.setCrfAnnotHeight(annot.getCrfAnnotHeight() + borderWidth);
    float locationX = annot.getCrfAnnotLocationX();
    if (rotate == 90.0 || rotate == 270.0) {​​​​​
        if (locationX + annot.getCrfAnnotWidth() >= ipage.getHeight()) {
            ​​​​​locationX = ipage.getHeight() - annot.getCrfAnnotWidth();
        }
    ​}
    else {​​​​​
        if (locationX + annot.getCrfAnnotWidth() >= ipage.getWidth()) {​​​​​
            locationX = ipage.getWidth() - annot.getCrfAnnotWidth();
        }
    ​​​​​}​​​​​
    Rectangle rect = getRectangle(ipage, locationX, annot.getCrfAnnotLocationY(), annot.getCrfAnnotWidth() + 2, annot.getCrfAnnotHeight() + 2, rotate);
    annotation = PdfAnnotation.createFreeText(pdfCopy, rect, annot.getCrfAnnotText(), cb);
    annotation = rotateAnnot(annotation, rotate);
    annotation = setAnnotFontColor(annotation, colorConfig.getColorConfigFontColor(), colorConfig.getColorConfigVariableFontSize(), colorConfig.getColorConfigFontBold(), colorConfig.getVariableItalics(), colorConfig.getColorSchemaBorderColorVariable(), colorConfig.getColorSchemaTextAlignmentVariable(), colorConfig.getColorConfigFontType());
    annotation.setColor(getBaseColor(colorConfig.getColorConfigBackColor()));
    if(containsOrEqualItalic(annot.getCrfAnnotText(), italicKeywordsVariableList)) {​​​​​
        PdfString _Str = new PdfString(italicHelper(annot.getCrfAnnotText(), italicKeywordsVariableList));
        annotation.put(PdfName.RC, _Str);
        annotation.put(PdfName.AP, null);
    }
    ​​​​​if (borderWidth > 0) {
        annotation.setBorderStyle(new PdfBorderDictionary(borderWidth, PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_SOLID));
    }
    PageStamp pageStamp = pdfCopy.createPageStamp(ipage);
    pageStamp.addAnnotation(annotation);
}
catch (DocumentException e) {​​​​​e.printStackTrace();}​​​​​ 
catch (IOException e) {​​​​​e.printStackTrace();}​​​​​
```

This code can add annotations to pdf file successfully, but I can't find this annotation when I use <kbd>Ctrl+f</kbd> in Acrobat Reader to find the annotations contents.

Comment: Your code contains many undefined variables, so we cannot simply run it to try and reproduce your issue. Please provide an example PDF file created by your code illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not all pdf readers can search inside annotation as they are encapsulated objects, however Adobe Reader should have the ability to extend/include a search inside annotation.

Adobe "Find" does not "search" in comments or all other annotation objects:-

[image]

However you can extend "Search" to include  annotation:-

[image]

However your code suggests you are using "Free Text" and Reader "Find" "should" be able to read that without extending as shown here:- (but not all readers can)

[image]